# wiotp out Node-RED node on Raspberry Pi connects to Watson IoT and stays disconnected after flow change

Tags: watson-iot

I added a wiotp out node to the flow and created a device on the Watson IoT platform. The initial connect was successful and logged on the platform:

```
Token auth succeeded: ClientID='d:ltxxxx:RaspberryPi:RPi3', ClientIP=146.52.28.xxx
```

I then added an Inject node, deployed again and the wiotp out node remains disconnected.

WIOTP log:

```
Closed connection from 146.52.28.xxx. The connection has completed normally.
```

Node-RED output:

```
[BaseClient:connect] Iotfclient is offline. Retrying connection
[BaseClient:onClose] Connection was closed.
```

Answer (score 2):

rebooted the Raspbarry Pi, reconnected and it's working for now